# Vb.Net 2010 ListBox

Tags: vb.net, list

So I am trying to code something in vb.net 2010 which will have a list box.

For example:

```
1) Apple 
2) Pizza
3) Juice
```

How would I display Line number 2 or any other to the user - I tried doing it with a label box like this
Label1.Text = ListBox1.Text(2) - does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Label1.Text = ListBox1.Items(1).ToString()
```

if you want to get the Text of the currently selected item then you can do

```
If ListBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
    Label1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox("List box item 1: " & ListBox1.Items(0), MsgBoxStyle.Information)
MsgBox("List box item 2: " & ListBox1.Items(1), MsgBoxStyle.Information)
MsgBox("List box item 3: " & ListBox1.Items(2), MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```